# DNS query always returns 127.0.0.1

Tags: dns

Any idea why dns request returns 127.0.0.1 for this particular (garage.dyn.woima.fi) domain, other domains are working fine ? 192.168.255.1 ip address has been assigned to my home network ADSL box.

```
dig garage.dyn.woima.fi

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> garage.dyn.woima.fi
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 63842
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;garage.dyn.woima.fi.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
garage.dyn.woima.fi.    846 IN  A   127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 4 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.255.1#53(192.168.255.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Aug 27 16:52:47 EEST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 53
```

The result is exactly same even I forced different name server in dig command ? If I make query from internet it gives correct ip.

```
 dig dyn.woima.fi NS

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> dyn.woima.fi NS
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dyn.woima.fi.          IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
dyn.woima.fi.       900 IN  NS  ns2.woima.fi.
dyn.woima.fi.       900 IN  NS  ns1.woima.fi.
dyn.woima.fi.       900 IN  NS  ns3.woima.fi.


root@garage:~# dig @ns2.woima.fi garage.dyn.woima.fi

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> @ns2.woima.fi garage.dyn.woima.fi
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 18922
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1680
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;garage.dyn.woima.fi.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
garage.dyn.woima.fi.    900 IN  A   127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 18 msec
;; SERVER: 164.215.38.200#53(164.215.38.200)
;; WHEN: Sun Aug 27 17:00:09 EEST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 64
```

- Jake

Comment: Because that what's in the dns data? It's `127.0.0.1` from my system, too.

Comment: It should return domain ip address instead of 127.0.0.1, like this                dig garagepc.hopto.org

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> garagepc.hopto.org
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;garagepc.hopto.org.  IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
garagepc.hopto.org. 60 IN A 91.156.35.83

;; Query time: 40 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.255.1#53(192.168.255.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Aug 27 20:56:38 EEST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 52
Did you get my point ?